# Time taken by set vs list with for and if

Tags: python, list, data-structures, set

I have two collections and i need to find if the two collections have anything in common and if they do what are they.
I can do it using lists and for and if or sets and finding the intersection.
but I also need to minimize the time taken to run.

Which of the two approaches is more time efficient?
Note: Differences of the scale of a second is also important.

EDIT:
What i mean by collection is a collection of values. read from a csv for example. i may put them in a list or set for further operations.
Example:
a = ['D','C','B','A']
b = ['A','B',E',Z','N','W']

Now i can do it in the following ways?

```
common=[]
for item in a:
    if item not in b:
        common.append(item)
```

using list comprehension

```
common=[item for item in a if item not in b]
```

using set

```
set(a) & set(b)
```

I am unable to use just time command from linux since that is varying hugely from system to system

Comment: What is a *collection*? You mean some member of the `collections` module? How do you *do it using lists and for and if or sets*? Please show some code.

Comment: Implement both. Measure. There's your answer.

Comment: Implement both for 100,000 elements or so and just see what happens man.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about time "varying hugely from system to system". It doesn't matter if it's not consistent between systems, you only need to measure on *one* system to find out which method is faster.

Comment: Assuming that a and b are both sets, then the middle one should be better since it'll be done in C. If a and b are lists with a fair bit of elements then "set(a) & set(b)" should be faster. Otherwise, it's a toss up between the middle and the last with a slight chance for the first one. Actually, as others have mentioned, it's best to just it time or profile it anyway if you're concerned about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Which method is faster?" Questions almost always have the same answer: profile it and find out. Speed is affected by too many variables for useful speculative answers.

That being said, your comprehension option is almost certainly going to be faster than the for loop option, because [implicit loops are generally faster than explicit ones](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops). Note that even the documentation in that link has this caveat:

> Which method is appropriate will depend on what version of Python you're using and the characteristics of the data you are manipulating.

I don't fully understand your concern about using the Linux time command, it. The total [CPU time](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) reported by time is a decent way to calculate the total time your script takes to run. This doesn't give you the resolution to check the efficiency of your loop in particular, but if you don't see a difference in the output of time between your three methods, then it isn't a bottleneck and you shouldn't worry about it anyway.

**TL;DR**
There is no shortcut around profiling. Use any of the [Python's Profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to identify your bottlenecks and focus your attention on them. The profiler output will tell you which of your proposed methods is the best in *your* case for the data that *you* are processing.